# Covariances of a random variable and its subset

Tags: probability, self-study, covariance, subset

Suppose event B is a subset of event A.
$P(A) = p$ and $P(B) = q$.

What is the Covariance of indicator functions from A and B. 
$$ \mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega) = \begin{cases}
1 & \omega \in A\\
0 & \omega\notin A
\end{cases}
$$
I know that Covariance can be written as 
$$ Cov(\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega),\mathbb{1}_{B}(\omega)) = E(\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{B}(\omega)) - E(\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega))E(\mathbb{1}_{B}(\omega)) = E(\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{B}(\omega)) - pq$$

To get the first term, I try to calculate:
$$E(\mathbb{1}_{A}(\omega)\mathbb{1}_{B}(\omega)) = \sum_{i,j} \omega_i\omega_jP(A = \omega_i, B = \omega_j) $$

I'm not really sure how to advance from here since I don't know the joint probability or what happens to probabilities/moments when something one event is a subset of another.

Comment: You lost crucial symbols in your final equation.  Maybe it's a typographical error?  By definition, the expectation is an integral (or a sum in the discrete case, as implied here) of products of *values* and *probabilities.*  Since the $\omega_i$ are abstract objects, they aren't values at all. Moreover, since $A$ and $B$ are *sets*, equations like "$A=\omega_i$" are of little relevance and certainly have no probabilities.  Thus, this sum makes no sense at all.  Perhaps you mean $$E[1_A\, 1_B] = \sum_{\omega} 1_A(\omega)1_B(\omega)\Pr(\omega)\ \text{?}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $B \subseteq A$ you have $(1_B = 1) \implies (1_A = 1)$ which gives you covariance:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{Cov}(1_A, 1_B) 
&= \mathbb{E}(1_A 1_B) - \mathbb{E}(1_A)\mathbb{E}(1_B) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(1_B) - \mathbb{E}(1_A)\mathbb{E}(1_B) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(1_B) (1 - \mathbb{E}(1_A)) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(B) (1 - \mathbb{P}(A)) \\[6pt]
&= q (1 - p).
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

The corresponding correlation is:

$$\mathbb{Corr}(1_A, 1_B) = \frac{q(1-p)}{\sqrt{p(1-p)q(1-q)}} = \sqrt{\frac{q}{p} \cdot \frac{1-p}{1-q}}.$$

Since $B \subseteq A$ you have $q \leqslant p$ so the correlation coefficient cannot exceed one (a useful check on the result).